# Is this a valid way to extend the proof of the insolubility of the quintic?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, solvable-groups

I'm just musing here, this is only (barely even) a half-formed idea, but I'm just wondering if it's at all a valid train of thought. The proof I read of the insolubility of the quintic polynomial rests on finding a particular quintic which is not solvable. Could a proof of the insolubility of all higher degree polynomials be formed out of the fact that if such a formula existed, say, for degree 6 polynomials, then I could solve an insolvable quintic polynomial by multiplying it by $x$, solving the polynomial I get as a result, then discarding the 0 solution given? Is that a contradiction? Or would that be possible given that there was some formula for higher degree polynomials?

Would it just be a "trick" to solve them?

Surely if one had a formula in the coefficients for a higher degree polynomial, they could then set to zero all coefficients that would become zero and get a formula for solving quintics.

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct.

Comment: The formula need not necessarily exist. The formula for quadratic equations, for example, does not work for $a=0$.

Comment: Be careful - the first version depends subtly on your notion of 'insolubility', and specifically whether the lack of solubility by radicals applies to _any_ or _all_ of the roots.  Instead, setting the leading coefficient to zero (rather than the constant coefficient) should work better.

Comment: The proof of the insolubility is hard and needs the abstract galois theory of groups.

Comment: So? Multiply a linear equation by x, solve using the quadratic formula, and discard the 0 solution

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct.

Comment: Why does this argument not work? Is it to do with the extra repeated 0 solutions that result?

Comment: Oh okay, these comments are up and down

Comment: I think my argument is correct because it would allow for closed form representations of numbers which have no closed form!

Comment: That's surely a contradiction if I've seen one

Comment: By the way, it's not true that *every* irreducible polynomial of degree at least 5 is unsolvable (in radicals). E.g., the polynomials $x^n-a$ are solvable for all positive integers $n$ and all rational $a$. The correct statements are 1) for each $n\ge5$, there exist unsolvable irreducible polynomials of degree $n$, and 2) if $n\ge5$ then there is no general formula for the solution of a polynomial of degree $n$ in terms of radicals.

Comment: Now, for going from, say, degree 5 to degree 6, it's no good just multiplying by $x$, because that gives you a *reducible* polynomial, and the theory is not about those. Nor can you go argue from 6th degree polynomials with leading coefficient zero, since these aren't really 6th degree polynomials. I think you have to argue that there are 6th degree polynomials with Galois group $S_6$, and that $S_6$ is not a solvable group.